# setting up iterative item query in python

Tags: python, recursion, iteration

I am trying to set up a function that will query an item for its sub components if those exists and return those else return the item itself.

Imagine an object that can contain more objects within it. To access those objects i would do `object.GetSubComponentIds()` now if that object contains sub objects it would return a list of those sub objects or EmptyList if there are none. In case that there are sub objects contained within it I want to keep going and then for each subobject i want to check if there are any subobjects contained within them. So for every `SubObject.GetSubComponentIds()` now if those do not contain anything then i would love to return them while maintaining nested structure of objects that they came from.

object1(contains 3 sub objects)
object2(contains 3 sub object and each sub object contains one more sub object)
object3(does not contain sub objects)

`inputlist = [object1, object2]`

`outputlist = [[obj1sub1, obj1sub2, obj1sub3],[[obj2sub1sub1],[obj2sub2sub1],[obj2sub3sub1]],[obj3]]`

I am interested in maintaining that nested list structure that will allow me to always trace back the origin of the sub object. Again, a method to get a sub object list is `object.GetSubComponentIds()` and it will either return a `list` or `Empty List`.

Can anyone help me set up an iterative function to retrieve them. Keep in mind that I do not know whether there are any sub objects contained within an object or haw many levels deep are they. It's basically that if it returns a list i need to check every item on that list for more sub objects.

Thank you in advance

Here's my humble first try:

```
#unwrap all elements to use with API
elements = []
for i in IN[0]:
    elements.append(UnwrapElement(i))

#create element set from python list
elementSet = Autodesk.Revit.DB.ElementSet()
for i in elements:
    elementSet.Insert(i)

#convert element set to List[Element]
setForCheck = List[Autodesk.Revit.DB.Element]()
elemIter = elementSet.ForwardIterator()
elemIter.Reset()
while elemIter.MoveNext():
    curElem = elemIter.Current
    setForCheck.Add(curElem)

#iterate throuh all elements to extract nested elements
setLoop = List[Autodesk.Revit.DB.Element]()
elemSet = List[Autodesk.Revit.DB.Element]()
itemOut = []
counter = 0
while setForCheck.Count >= 1:
    setLoop.Clear()
    for i in setForCheck:
        itemOut.append(i)
        if i.GetSubComponentIds().Count >= 1:
            elem = Autodesk.Revit.DB.ElementSet()
            for j in i.GetSubComponentIds():
                elem.Insert(doc.GetElement(j))
            elemIterA = elem.ForwardIterator()
            elemIterA.Reset()
            while elemIterA.MoveNext():
                curElemA = elemIterA.Current
                setLoop.Add(curElemA)
    setForCheck.Clear()
    elemIterB = setLoop.GetEnumerator()
    elemIterB.Reset()
    while elemIterB.MoveNext():
        curElemB = elemIterB.Current
        setForCheck.Add(curElemB)
    counter += 1
    if counter > 1000:
         break

#Assign your output to the OUT variable
OUT = itemOut
```

Comment: This sounds a lot like homework... What have you tried?

Comment: Well I dont think that my logic is right because what this method returns is a flat list of all sub objects, and it also includes the original objects. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using some specific libraries, like `Autodesk`, that I'm not familiar with. Let me answer your question in terms of an abstract example.

Suppose we're dealing with `Thing` objects, where `Thing` is defined as:

```
class Thing(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.inside = []
```

We can make `Thing`s and put other things inside of them. The example you give in your post can be written:

```
ob1 = Thing("ob1")
ob1.inside.extend([Thing("ob1sub1"), Thing("ob1sub2"), Thing("ob1sub3")])

ob2 = Thing("ob2")
for i in xrange(1,4):
    name = "ob2sub{}".format(i)
    thing = Thing(name)
    thing.inside.append(Thing(name + "sub1"))
    ob2.inside.append(thing)

ob3 = Thing("ob3")

things = [ob1, ob2, ob3]
```

This makes a sort of tree. Now we'd like to return a nested list of all of the leaf nodes in the tree:

```
def search_things(things):
    names = []
    for thing in things:
        if not thing.inside:
            names.append(thing)
        else:
            names.append(search_things(thing.inside))

    return names
```

A test:

```
>>> search_things(things)
[['ob1sub1', 'ob1sub2', 'ob1sub3'],
 [['ob2sub1sub1'], ['ob2sub2sub1'], ['ob2sub3sub1']],
 'ob3']
```

I'll let you transform this to your specific problem, but this is the general idea. Note that the algorithm is recursive, not iterative. You said you wanted an iterative algorithm -- and the above can be written iteratively -- but this gives you the idea.

Comment: This is great! This is exactly what I was hoping for. I am still having trouble defining recursive functions so this helps a lot. Thanks!